# Sawtooth Marketplace how offers and assets are stored in rethink db?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-sawtooth

There is rethink db which stores blocks, assets, Offers etc. in rethink db.
I am able to find how authentication details are getting stored but i am not able to find the from where the assets and offers are getting stored in the database please help me with that

Comment: They are likely being stored as a result of Events (which are subscribed to) from sawtooth. Look for the event subscription and event listeners in marketplace

Comment: Yeah I did found that there is an event handler who is doing all this Thank You @FrankC.